# Deleted Function Still available

Tags: bash, shell, centos

I created a function called "tardir" to compress specific directories and added it to my .bash_profile on my CentOS box.

Since then ive created a bunch of other scripts and instead of adding them to my .bash_profile, I created a scripts folder and add the path to the $PATH export in my .bash_profile.

I then removed the tardir function from .bash_profile and converted it to shell script.  I ran source .bash_profile to refresh it, but what i have noticed is that the command tardir still works.

I have made changes to the shell script but the function tardir is still running old code and i cant locate it.

When I type tardir 'tab' 'tab' I get two results, tardir and tardir.sh

Where is the tardir coming from?  Is there flush cache command i can run to remove the old tardir function call completely?

Comment: THIS QUESTION CAN BE MAKED CLOSED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is defined in current process (shell) environment,

```
typeset -f tardir
```

to delete it start a new instance of bash, otherwise a function can be deleted in current process:

```
unset tardir
```

sourcing .bash_profile just run the commands in .bash_profile in current shell environment but doesn't reset environment.

Comment: I just needed to close my shell and launch a new one (duh).  I validated others were not seeing the old code so i guess the issues was between the keyboard and chair this time.